# Make something happen after clicking on an image 20 times HTML CSS JS

Tags: html, css

I've tried google and it just doesnt help me right now. I am trying to make a rickroll that happens after you click on an image 20 times, but I have no idea where to start, can anyone help me? or even better present some code that works in stack overflow so I can see.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a counter that you increment in the click event handler.

```js
let counter = 0;
document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', e => {
  ++counter;
  if (counter === 5) { //change to any number you want
    //do something
    console.log('clicked 5 times');
  }
});
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/html5.gif" />
```

Comment: This is great! but it only lets you do it once per page load. any way to fix this?

Comment: @xCREEPA What did you want instead?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I want it to work basically all the time, so if they click on it and it opens the new tab thus rickrolling them, but when they close the youtube page they go back to the main page and it wont let them do it again. is there any way to basically let it do that. Something else I would want, is for them to click it 20 times very quickly, or if not the counter resets.

Comment: side note, how would i make it redirect to the site?